# CipherInputStream could not reach last block in java

Tags: java, stream, encryption

I'm using CipherInputStream for decrypting an CipherOutputStream. It works but it could not get the last block.

What should I do?

Here is my codes:
receiver:

```
CipherInputStream csin = new CipherInputStream(in,mit.outCipher);
            while ((count = csin.read(buf)) != -1) {
                System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, count));
                outputStreams[local].write(buf, 0, count);
            }
```

and sender:

```
CipherOutputStream csout = new CipherOutputStream(outputStreams[local],mit.inCipher);
            while ((count = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                System.out.print(new String(buf, 0, count));
                csout.write(buf, 0, count);
            }
```

I should say that these codes work well without encryption.

Comment: Do you call `close()` on your streams?

Comment: yes. I call close on CipherOutputStream.

Comment: What happens instead? Moss ogling data? Block in read()?